# 403 error accessing solr 8.11 on tomcat 9 (Windows)

Tags: solr, http-status-code-403, tomcat9

When I access solr home page (solr 8.11 on tomcat 9, Windows), I get 403 unauthorised access. On same host/port other web app is running ok.

I am using web app code as it is which is part of solr set up. Logs indicate that deployment is ok and I dont see any errors.

Options tried
1 machine reboot
2 running command line with administrative privilege
3 checked configuration for any block
4 used local host,ip address

Could any one suggest ways on how could this be fixed ?